# Can I retrieve a map value by a key Predicate?

Tags: java

I have a `Map<MidiInstrument, List<JCheckBox>> instrumentMap` with `MidiInstrument` being a simple record

```java
public record MidiInstrument(String name, int firstByte) {
}
```

Now, I parse an external file and retrieve an instrument's name only. I should try and see whether my map has a corresponding instrument and, if so, perform some operations on the value (the list). If only I had some `getByPredicate()` method, I could

```java
List<JCheckBox> checkBoxList = instrumentMap.getByPredicate(instrument -> instrument.name().equals(instrumentName));
if (checkBoxList != null) {
    // perform some business logic
}
```

Is there some method (external libraries included) that can do this trick or something to that effect? Unfortunately, `Map` doesn't have such a method

**UPD:** I did find a workaround, but it's clumsy

```java
    private class LoadButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
            fileChooser.showSaveDialog(mainPanel);
            try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileChooser.getSelectedFile()))) {
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] keyValuePair = line.split(KEY_VALUE_SEPARATOR);
                    Optional<Map.Entry<MidiInstrument, List<JCheckBox>>> optionalEntry;
                    if ((optionalEntry = instrumentMap.entrySet().stream()
                            .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().name().equals(keyValuePair[0]))
                            .findFirst()) // instead of this ugly stream we could've had getByPredicate()...
                            .isPresent()) {
                        String[] marks = keyValuePair[1].split("");
                        List<JCheckBox> checkBoxList = optionalEntry.get().getValue();
                        for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxList.size(); i++) {
                            var currentCheckBox = checkBoxList.get(i);
                            if (marks[i].equals(CHECK_MARK)) {
                                currentCheckBox.setSelected(true);
                            } else if (marks[i].equals(BLANK_MARK)) {
                                currentCheckBox.setSelected(false);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can loop through the map's entries with a stream, but I think that loses the point of using a map in the first place. How about using two maps - a `Map<String, List<JCheckBox>>` and a `Map<String, Integer>`?

Comment: I know it's a two step process, but I might have a `Map<String, MidiInstrument>` or just find the instrument in a `List` directly ‍♂️

Comment: What's the point of this map if you don't use the key for the lookup?

Comment: @daniu to group properties together

Comment: So group them by name. If that is not unique enough, you'll have problem with any solution you'll find for this question.

Comment: @daniu what are values going to be? My current approach is flexible: I can add more fields to `MidiInstrument` and extend the functionality more easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that hard to build the `getByPredicate` method:

```
public static <K, V> Optional<V> getByPredicate(Map<K, V> map, Predicate<? super K> predicate) {
    return map.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(entry -> predicate.test(entry.getKey()))
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .findAny();
}
```

Comment: Highly inefficient though. This turns O(1) key lookup into O(n) linear search

Comment: @knittl true, but the only way to solve that is by using a different map key, like Baptiste's example. There's no way to directly map the predicate to a single entry.

Comment: Yeah, I did a similar thing (see the edit)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need to do is to use the instrument's `name` as the identifier that you use to identify and store/retrieve data for it. In the end, you'll keep a `Map<String, MidiInstrument>` maintaining the overall data; the checkboxes you can store in a `Map<String, List<JCheckbox>>` (although it's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve with that anyway).

Then you'd have something like

```
MidiInstrument instrument = instrumentByName.get(name);
List<JCheckbox> checkboxes = checkboxMap.get(instrument);
```

I feel the "checkboxes by instrument" map does have a code smell to it, but I guess it might have its justification. It looks like you use it to load settings from a file - this is not a case requiring heavy optimization, so a double lookup should be fine.

Actually, performancewise, your solution should also not be a problem. If you're worried about the code not looking nice, just create a `List<Checkbox> getCheckboxesByInstrumentName(String)` method or interface and hide it there. If it still bothers you, use the second map.

Answer (score 0):

If you can refactor the Map, a simple solution would be to use something like a `Map<String, Pair<MidiInstrument, List<JCheckBox>>>` and create the map by using the name as the key.

Where `Pair` would be an object representing a pair of objects. Apache and Spring provide a basic implementation of it. Otherwise, it's a simple generic record that you can create :

```java
public record Pair<T, V>(T first, V second) {}
```

Any iteration over the `Map` to search for what you want instead of using his inner mechanisms will be less efficient.

Comment: Thank you. The drawback of this approach is that I can't add more attributes to the group. On the other hand, I can add more fields to `MidiInstrument` with no problems